# Mongoose.js Docs with nested subdocs, which have nested subdocs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to integrating a system of commenting into my project. There are two models: the post and the comments. posts have an array for comments, and comments have an array for replies.
When I get the posts on the frontend, I am able to see the comments just fine, but not the replies.
However, when I visit the mongoDB atlas site, the issue is the same: the post document shows the comments but now the comment's replies. However, the individual document for the comment does indeed show the replies within the array.
Below is an example of the function used to save comments to posts - the variant for saving replies to comments is the same.

Could anyone explain why this is occuring?

```
await Posts.findOneAndUpdate(
          {_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.parentID)},
          {$push: {comments: newComment}},
          [{upsert: true}, {useFindandModify: false}]).then((data) => {
            if(data) {
              console.log(`comment ${newComment._id} was made to a post ${newComment.parentID}`);
              res.status(200).send(true);
            } else {
              console.log(`error in adding comment ${newComment._id} to post ${newComment.parentID}`);
            }
    })
```

The intention is that the posts doc includes both the comments and the comment's replies. Right now , the replies array for comments is empty.

Ive only used fetch requests to pull a list of post documents. However, whenever a comment is made on the front end, the individual post is again fetch to refresh the page.